# Sort contact list list alphabetically

Tags: android, list, sorting, listview, adapter

Hello i need help in sorting contact list in my App alphabetically. App check which device contact is registered in app and place them on app contact list. i have custom  simple cursor adapter.:

```
package com.loopg.adapters;

                import android.content.Context;
                import android.database.Cursor;
                import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
                import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.ViewGroup;
                import android.widget.AlphabetIndexer;
                import android.widget.CheckBox;
                import android.widget.SectionIndexer;
                import android.widget.TextView;

                import com.loopg.R;
                import com.loopg.db.AppContacts;
                import com.loopg.db.AppContactsData;
                import com.loopg.db.AppProfiles;

                import java.util.HashMap;
                import java.util.Iterator;
                import java.util.Map;
                import java.util.Set;
                import java.util.TreeMap;

                public class AllContactsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

                    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
                    private static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 0;

                    private static final int TYPE_COUNT = 2;
                    public HashMap<String, Boolean> hmSelected = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
                    public int selectedContacts = 0;
                    Cursor mCursor = null;
                    private AlphabetIndexer indexer;
                    private int[] usedSectionNumbers;
                    private Map<Integer, Integer> sectionToOffset;
                    private Map<Integer, Integer> sectionToPosition;
                    private boolean showSelection = false;
                    private int rowCount = 0;
                    private int selectedNumbers = 0;
                    private Context invokerContext = null;
                    private String appStatus = "";
                    private String inviteStatus = "";

                    private String sectionHeaders = "#GHGJHJHKHJKGJHKLKJHGF";

                    public AllContactsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int layout, boolean forInvite) {
                        super(context, layout, c, new String[]{}, new int[]{}, 0);
                        invokerContext = context;
                        showSelection = forInvite;
                        mCursor = c;

                        initialize();

                        appStatus = context.getString(R.string.tw_default_status);
                        inviteStatus = context.getString(R.string.hf_invite_status);

                    }

                    public AllContactsAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
                        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
                        super.changeCursor(cursor);

                        mCursor = cursor;

                        initialize();
                    }

                    private void initialize() {

                        hmSelected = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

                        rowCount = mCursor.getCount();

                        indexer = new AlphabetIndexer(mCursor, mCursor.getColumnIndex(AppContacts.CLS.CONTACT_NAME), sectionHeaders);
                        // use a TreeMap because we are going to iterate over its keys in sorted
                        // order
                        sectionToPosition = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
                        sectionToOffset = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

                        final int count = super.getCount();

                        int i;
                        // temporarily have a map alphabet section to first index it appears
                        // (this map is going to be doing something else later)
                        for (i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            sectionToPosition.put(indexer.getSectionForPosition(i), i);
                        }

                        i = 0;
                        usedSectionNumbers = new int[sectionToPosition.keySet().size()];

                        // note that for each section that appears before a position, we must
                        // offset our
                        // indices by 1, to make room for an alphabetical header in our list
                        for (Integer section : sectionToPosition.keySet()) {
                            sectionToOffset.put(section, i);
                            usedSectionNumbers[i] = section;
                            i++;
                        }

                        // use offset to map the alphabet sections to their actual indicies in
                        // the list
                        for (Integer section : sectionToPosition.keySet()) {
                            sectionToPosition.put(section, sectionToPosition.get(section) + sectionToOffset.get(section));
                        }

                        if (showSelection) {
                            initializeSelection();
                        }
                        selectedContacts = 0;
                    }

                    private void initializeSelection() {

                        int position = mCursor.getPosition();

                        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                String id = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

                                hmSelected.put(id, false);
                            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
                        }

                        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

                        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AppContacts.CLS.CONTACT_NAME));
                        String status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AppProfiles.CLS.STATUS));
                        if (status == null || status.length() == 0) {
                            int appUser = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AppContactsData.CLS.CONTACT_APP_USER));
                            if (appUser == AppContacts.APP_USER)
                                status = appStatus;
                            else
                                status = inviteStatus;
                        }

                        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

                        view.setTag(id);

                        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_ContactName);
                        tv.setText(name);
                        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_ContactStatus);
                        tv.setText(status);

                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.id_cb_ContactSelected);
                        if (showSelection) {
                            // registerForClickListner(cb);
                            if (cb.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
                                cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            boolean checked = hmSelected.get(id) == null ? false : hmSelected.get(id);
                            if (checked) {
                                cb.setChecked(true);
                            } else {
                                cb.setChecked(false);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (cb.getVisibility() != View.GONE)
                                cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.view_contact_row, null);

                        return view;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        if (super.getCount() != 0) {
                            return super.getCount() + usedSectionNumbers.length;
                        }

                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getItem(int position) {
                        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_NORMAL) {// we define this
                            return super.getItem(position - sectionToOffset.get(getSectionForPosition(position)) - 1);
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
                        if (!sectionToOffset.containsKey(section)) {
                            int i = 0;
                            int maxLength = usedSectionNumbers.length;
                            while (i < maxLength && section > usedSectionNumbers[i]) {
                                i++;
                            }
                            if (i == maxLength)
                                return getCount(); // the given section is past all our data

                            return indexer.getPositionForSection(usedSectionNumbers[i]) + sectionToOffset.get(usedSectionNumbers[i]);
                        }

                        return indexer.getPositionForSection(section) + sectionToOffset.get(section);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
                        int i = 0;
                        int maxLength = usedSectionNumbers.length;

                        // linear scan over the used alphabetical sections' positions
                        // to find where the given section fits in
                        while (i < maxLength && position >= sectionToPosition.get(usedSectionNumbers[i])) {
                            i++;
                        }
                        return usedSectionNumbers[i - 1];
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object[] getSections() {
                        return indexer.getSections();
                    }

                    // nothing much to this: headers have positions that the sectionIndexer
                    // manages.
                    @Override
                    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                        if (position == getPositionForSection(getSectionForPosition(position))) {
                            return TYPE_HEADER;
                        }
                        return TYPE_NORMAL;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getViewTypeCount() {
                        return TYPE_COUNT;
                    }

                    // return the header view, if it's in a section header position
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        final int type = getItemViewType(position);
                        if (type == TYPE_HEADER) {
                            if (convertView == null) {
                                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(invokerContext).inflate(R.layout.view_list_header, parent, false);
                            }
                            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_ListHeader)).setText((String) getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
                            return convertView;
                        }
                        return super.getView(position - sectionToOffset.get(getSectionForPosition(position)) - 1, convertView, parent);
                    }


                    // these two methods just disable the headers
                    @Override
                    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_HEADER) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }



                    public void selectAll() {
                        Set<String> set = hmSelected.keySet();
                        Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator();

                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            String id = iterator.next();

                            hmSelected.put(id, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and here is where i set the adapter:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_all_contacts, null);

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + AppContactsData.TABLE_CONTACT_DATA + " LEFT JOIN " + AppContacts.TABLE_CONTACT_NAMES + " ON "
            + AppContactsData.CLS.CONTACT_ID + "=" + AppContacts.CLS.CONTACT_ID + " LEFT JOIN " + AppProfiles.TABLE_PROFILES + " ON "
            + AppProfiles.CLS.USER_NUMBER + "=" + AppContactsData.CLS.CONTACT_E164NUMBER + " where " + AppContactsData.CLS.CONTACT_ID
            + "!=0";

    query = query + " ORDER BY " + AppContacts.CLS.CONTACT_NAME + " collate nocase";

    cursor = DBHelper.getInstance().executeRawQuery(query);

    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_lv_AllContacts);

    adapter = new AllContactsAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, R.layout.view_contact, showSelection);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Whats happening right now? Query seems fine, do you retrieve the data in alfabetical order?

Comment: contacts are not displayed in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will Help!

Change the line

query = query + " ORDER BY " + AppContacts.CLS.CONTACT_NAME + " collate nocase";

to like this

query = query + " ORDER BY " + AppContacts.CLS.CONTACT_NAME + " collate nocase **ASC** ";